# Display box on hover is "transparent"?

Tags: javascript, css, hover, html

Okay. I can't really explain this so I just made a fiddle.
So click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/acyNw/143/)

And the code looks something like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="#">Hover Me!<span class="tooltip">Hello, World!</span></a><br>
<a href="#">Hover This!<span class="tooltip">Hello, People!</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
a span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
a {
    position: relative;
}
a:hover span {
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also I got some more `<a>` css, but I don't think this is the problem..

```
a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

If you hover the first text, the box that appears won't cover the second text. 
Basically the text is always the first and the box goes under it.

How do I fix this? It's very important or else my design won't  work.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Give it a higher `z-index`..? http://jsfiddle.net/YrABh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a large `z-index` style, these determine the layer of the html object.

```
<a href="#" style="z-index:9999998;">Hover Me!<span class="tooltip">Hello, World!</span></a><br>
<a href="#">Hover This!<span class="tooltip">Hello, People!</span></a>
```

Comment: Yep. the other guy was faster but I'm going to reward you since he commented